# ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified error when running rspec with rails 4.1

Tags: rails-activerecord, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have not been able to find this exact error anywhere else on Google or on stackoverflow.

I am running Rails 4.1.0 and rspec-rails 3.0.0.beta2

When trying to run $rspec, I get the following error:

```
    DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a string to ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection for a configuration lookup is deprecated, please pass a symbol (:development) instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/sam/code/rails/innovacert/spec/spec_helper.rb:4)
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:257:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["test"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:240:in `resolve_string_connection'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:267:in `resolve_hash_connection'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:228:in `resolve_connection'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:152:in `resolve'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:164:in `block in resolve_all'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:163:in `each'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:163:in `resolve_all'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:48:in `block in <module:Core>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `class_eval'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `append_features'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:297:in `include'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:297:in `<class:Base>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:282:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/rails/extensions/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<module:Extensions>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/rails/extensions/active_record/base.rb:4:in `<module:Rails>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/rails/extensions/active_record/base.rb:2:in `<module:RSpec>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/rails/extensions/active_record/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/rails/extensions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/rails.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/sam/code/rails/innovacert/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sam/code/rails/innovacert/spec/validators/rut_validator_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/sam/code/rails/innovacert/spec/validators/rut_validator_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:932:in `load'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:932:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:932:in `each'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:932:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in `run'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:31:in `invoke'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

The error is being generated from a "require 'rspec/rails'" in spec_helper.rb.

I don't understand why this is happening as I have my test database configured properly in database.yml:

```
    default: &default
  host: localhost
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: innovacert_development
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASS'] %>

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: innovacert_test
  username: sam
  password:
```

From this line:

/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:257:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["test"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

IT would appear that rspec is trying to look for a database called :development. Yet in spec_helper.rb I explicitly define:

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"

I have used pry to take a look at this variable and it is definitely being assigned as 'test'.

Why is rspec failing?

Comment: Have same problem too: environment development, database configured, but after server run i got this error: `resolve_symbol_connection': 'production' database is not configured. Available: ["development"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

Comment: Do you have a sample application in github (need the source code to download and run) that reproduces this issue?  Often times I find it's easier to try and reproduce the bug in a small application.